# How to insert a new line after each occurrence of a particular format in a text field

Tags: regex, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a system that I can output a spreadsheet from. I then take this outputted spreadsheet and import it into MS Access. There, I run some basic update queries before merging the final result into a SharePoint 2013 Linked List.

The spreadsheet I output has an unfortunate Long Text field which has some comments in it, which are vital. On the system that hosts the spreadsheet, these comments are nicely formatted. When the spreadsheet it output though, the field turns into a long, very unpretty string like so:

> 09:00 on 01/03/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Have responded to request for more information. 15:12 on 15/02/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Need more information to progress request. 17:09 on 09/02/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Have placed request.

What I would like to do is run a query (either in MS Access or MS Excel) which can scan this field, detect occurrences of "##:## on ##/##/####, Firstname Surname. :-" and then automatically insert a line break before them, so this text is more neatly formatted. It would obviously skip the first occurrence of this format, as otherwise it would enter a new line at the start of the field. Ideal end result would be:

> 09:00 on 01/03/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Have responded to request
>   for more information.
>   15:12 on 15/02/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Need more information to progress request.
>   17:09 on 09/02/2017, Firstname Surname. :- Have placed request.

To be honest, I haven't tried much myself so far, as I really don't know where to start. I don't know if this can be done without regular expressions, or within a simple query versus VBA code.

I did start building a regular expression, like so:

```
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[o][n]\s[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,\s
```

But this looks a little ridiculous and I'm fairly certain I'm going about it in a very unnecessary way. From what I can see from the text, detecting the next occurrence of "##:## on ##/##/####" should be enough. If I take a new line after this, that will suffice.

Comment: first row has 09*:*00 and following rows hh*.*mm is it a typo?

Comment: @krishKM It is, my mistake. I have corrected now.

Comment: can't you change the output and add delimiters? how are you importing if the output is not delimited?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I get no choice on how the file is output. I simply select the fields I want and it generates an Excel spreadsheet. So whatever I need to do has to be done from there onwards.

Comment: if you open your output in Excel, do you see the data in one column or in three columns?

Comment: The data is all in one column, in one single long string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your RegExp pattern, now you need to create a function to append found items with your extra delimiter.

look at this function. It takes, your long string and finds your date-stamp using your pattern and appends with your delimiter.

Ideally, i would run each line twice and add delimiters after each column so you have a string like,

datestamp;firstname lastname;comment

you can then use `arr = vba.split(text, ";")` to get your data into an array and use it as

```
date-stamp = arr(0)
name       = arr(1)
comment    = arr(2)


Public Function FN_REGEX_REPLACE(iText As String, iPattern As String, iDelimiter As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Dim allmatches As Variant

    Dim I As Long
   On Error GoTo FN_REGEX_REPLACE_Error

    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Multiline = True
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = iPattern

        If .test(iText) Then
            Set allmatches = .Execute(iText)
            If allmatches.count > 0 Then
                For I = 1 To allmatches.count - 1 ' for i = 0 to count will start from first match
                    iText = VBA.Replace(iText, allmatches.item(I), iDelimiter & allmatches.item(I))
                Next I
            End If
        End If
    End With

    FN_REGEX_REPLACE = Trim(iText)

    Set objRegex = Nothing

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

FN_REGEX_REPLACE_Error:
    MsgBox Err.description
End Function
```

use above function as

```
mPattern     = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[o][n]\s[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\,"
replacedText = FN_REGEX_REPLACE(originalText,mPattern,vbnewline)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I adapted it slightly, but it does what I need very well.

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses LF for linebreaks, Access uses CRLF.

So it should suffice to run a simple replacement query:

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET LongTextField = Replace([LongTextField], Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
WHERE <...>
```

You need to make sure that this runs only once on newly imported records, not repeatedly on all records.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. As I understand it, this will insert a carriage return. But how do I insert it where I want it, i.e. how do I match the particular part of the long text field that this needs to be executed in?

Comment: It would replace the single LF (Chr(10)) with CRLF. But re-reading your question, you wrote that the line break is already missing in Excel. So this may not be helpful. Copy a spreadsheet cell into a text (or hex) editor to see if there is a control character you can use.